# Failed to Abort() context - gin

Tags: go, go-gin

I have the following Gin middleware:

```
func CheckAppId(appC *core.Context) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        //get Basic Auth credentials
        appId, token, _ := c.Request.BasicAuth()

        if appId == "" {
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"code": "MISSING_APP_ID", "message": "Your request is missing an application id"})
            return //this is being ignored???
        }

        c.Next() //this still gets hit
    }
}
```

but if the `appId == ""` the JSON gets returned and `c.Next()` gets executed too. Is this expected behaviour?

**EDIT**
I thought the problem had been sold but the same thing appears to be happening. I now have:

```
func CheckAppId(appC *core.Context) gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        //get Basic Auth credentials
        appId, token, _ := c.Request.BasicAuth()

        if appId == "" {
            //I'm getting this JSON in the response
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"code": "MISSING_APP_ID", "message": "Your request is missing an application id"})
            c.Abort()
        }

        //find app_id in database
        app := core.App{}
        err := appC.Database.C("apps").Find(bson.M{"id" : appId}).One(&app)
        if err != nil { //no app found
            //and I'm getting this JSON in the response
            c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"code": "INVALID_APP_ID", "message": "The application id provided could not be found"})
            c.Abort()
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}
```

In a call to the API I receive both "MISSING_APP_ID" Json and "INVALID_APP_ID" Json

Comment: Are you sure that it actually hits that? Do a `fmt.Printf("%#v\n", appId)` right before `c.Next()`

Comment: In the response there is the JSON in the question and more JSON from the actual route that the request was for!

Answer (score 8):

Looking at the Gin API docs, you'll need to call [context.Abort()](http://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Context.Abort) instead of returning from your method.

> Abort stops the system to continue calling the pending handlers in the chain. Let's say you have an authorization middleware that validates if the request is authorized if the authorization fails (the password does not match). This method (Abort()) should be called in order to stop the execution of the actual handler.

So in your specific case

```
if appId == "" {
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"code": "MISSING_APP_ID", "message": "Your request is missing an application id"})
    c.Abort()
    return
}
```

Comment: Good spot - didn't see that

Comment: Unfortunately, after further testing I still have the same issues. Code beyond `c.Abort()` is still being executed for some reason?

Comment: I required `c.Abort()` and `return` as it happens

Comment: @tommyd456 whoops, sorry. Meant for the return to still be included. My mistake.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR**

You need to do:

```
if condition {
  c.Abort()
} else {
  c.Next()
}
```

**Explanation**

(Note: this builds on @Landers answer)

`c.Abort()` just sets some internal flags that mark the context in a certain way that indicates abnormal termination. It makes sense, it's a parameterless method that returns nothing, so you're only calling it for its side-effects.

Same thing with `c.Next()`

Because of go's control flow (no exceptions or jumps) its clear that these two methods don't take any immediate action but "set up the stage" for the next phase, imagine Gins code that calls your `CheckAppId` func:

```
// gin code
doStuff()
ctx := getContext()

// this is your CheckAppId
nextAction := FindAction()
nextAction(&ctx)

// here the context is evaluated to see if you either abort or continue.
checkContextStatus(&ctx)
```

So, if you're calling `c.Abort()` and then `c.Next()` you're overriding the abort indications.

Comment: Sorry if I've misunderstood but how do I then stop code being executed beyond the first `c.Abort()` - I don't want to query the database if the `appId` hasn't been provided. I can see my code ending up with many nested conditionals bearing in mind that the code above is a "trimmed" version of what I really have.

Comment: I guess adding a return statement after every `c.Abort()` and `c.Next()` unless its the last one.

Comment: Right - so a combination of both was what was needed - appreciate the help and explanation

Comment: Why is it that not calling c.Next() is not enough?